# Android - Firebase Storage Url as String

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

How can I get the download URL for an image I have stored in Firebase Storage as a String?

I have tried using the code in Firebase docs but I don't know how to get it as a String. Thanks.

```
storageRef.child("users/me/profile.png").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
    // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
}}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
    // Handle any errors
}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a `uri` object to String, please use the following line of code:

```
String stringUri = uri.toString();
```